# Batch script for Inkscape freezes at random points

Tags: batch-file, inkscape

I have a disc of over 5,000 world maps (as SVG files), and I wanted to extract a specific region of each map across a certain time period. So I wrote up a batch script that calls Inkscape in a loop, and crops each map between two specified dates.

Here is the code I used:

```
@echo off

set /A start=900
set /A end=1800
set x1=24073
set y1=22320
set x2=30708
set y2=28063
set width=900
set height=780
set output=Europe

set outpath=C:\Europe\
set inpath=D:\

set /A total=%end%-%start%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /l %%i in (0,1,%total%) do (

set /A t_date=%start%+%%i
set /A count=%%i+1
set aorb=X
if !t_date! lss 1 (set aorb=B
set /A t_date=!t_date!*-1
set /A t_date=!t_date!+1
) else (set aorb=A)

::Format input file (e.g., W[A|B]XXXX.svg)
set infile=!t_date!.svg
if !t_date! lss 1000 (set infile=0!infile!)
if !t_date! lss 100 (set infile=0!infile!)
if !t_date! lss 10 (set infile=0!infile!)
set infile=W!aorb!!infile!

::Format output file (e.g., Europe_XXXX.png)
set outfile=!count!.png
if !count! lss 1000 (set outfile=0!outfile!)
if !count! lss 100 (set outfile=0!outfile!)
if !count! lss 10 (set outfile=0!outfile!)
set outfile=%output%_!outfile!

::Most important line here
inkscape --export-area=%x1%:%y1%:%x2%:%y2% --export-png=%outpath%!outfile! --export-width=%width% --export-height=%height% %inpath%!infile!
::Echo count to keep track of progress
echo !count! of %total% maps complete
)

pause
```

Please excuse the lack of documentation. Most of this is just formatting the input and output filenames. Understandably, this code is very slow, and for date ranges of hundreds of years it would end up taking more than 12 hours to complete.

However, recently when I ran this code a new time, it seems to freeze at random points, giving nothing more than normal output like this:

```
63 of 900 maps complete
Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
Area 24073:22320:30708:28063 exported to 900 x 780 pixels (13.0385 dpi)
Bitmap saved as: 
C:\Europe\Europe_0064.png
```

1) The script isn't terminating 2) doesn't give any error message 3) doesn't progress in the code no matter how many hours I leave it be, and 4) does not appear to be caused by any external action, such as locking the computer for instance. In my experiments I see it stop at map number 5, 16, 63, or 118 among others, with absolutely no pattern between one instance or another. The only way I can proceed in this situation is to terminate the script with `ctrl+C`, delete any maps generated so far, and try again.

Is there anything known about either Batch scripts or Inkscape that could cause this kind of situation? What kind of things could I check or rule out?

I notice that sometimes Inkscape can have a problem of crashing on startup (this happens to me sometimes but not often enough to be a concern). Could the instance of Inkscape used by the batch script in the background similarly crash, thus causing it to get stuck?

Using Inkscape 0.92 on Windows 10

**EDIT** I used the `echo %time%` as suggested below and got the following result:

```
18:11:30.19
5 of 900 maps complete
18:11:30.19
Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
Area 24073:22320:30708:28063 exported to 900 x 780 pixels (13.0385 dpi)
Bitmap saved as: C:\Europe\Europe_0006.png
```

Which is the same as what I get for the original code, only with the time signature added in. However, strangely it seem that the exact same time signature is given for every single iteration of the code, almost as if the Inkscape command is not using any time at all. Is there something else I am missing here? In general this is certainly creating more questions than answers for me.

Comment: Add command `echo %time%` just before and just after inkscape command line and see what is printed out on screen. This should give you time of starting inkscape and time of termination inkscape. Or try to run inkscape command out of batch file, and see how long it running and if print any output. I dont see any possible delays in the code.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try that and see if it helps shed light on anything

Comment: Ok I added the results to my question above

Comment: How to begin debugging: (1) Comment out the `inkscape` line and see if the behavior persists. (2) `echo` the `inkscape` line before executing it.

Comment: Alex ok I did that and the behavior was exactly as expected: having the Inkscape command printed instead of executed printed the Inkscape command for every instance of the loop to the end of the program without any delays or freezing whatsoever. Each of these Inkscape commands was exactly as I expected them to be, for instance `inkscape --export-area=24073:22320:30708:28063 --export-png=C:\Europe\Europe_0900.png --export-width=900 --export-height=780 D:\WA1799.svg` does this shed any light on my original problem?

Comment: Just curious: couldn't you use Inkscape's interactive command line instead? It's fine for exporting, and it won't start Inkscape each and every time, but keep it running. Another thing I would try would be to do it in smaller batches and insert some wait time between them.